# Swashbuckle refuses to show response example for HTTP 500

Tags: swagger, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I'm using Swashbuckle for a web api app in .Net Core 3.1. I want response examples for various response codes. I can get all of them working except HTTP 500. These are the attributes on the a particular method:

```
    [SwaggerRequestExample(typeof(GroupInfoRequest), typeof(GroupInfoRequestExample))]
    [SwaggerResponseExample(Status200OK, typeof(GroupInfo200Example))]
    [SwaggerResponseExample(Status400BadRequest, typeof(GroupInfo400Example))]
    [SwaggerResponseExample(Status403Forbidden, typeof(GroupInfo403Example))]
    [SwaggerResponseExample(Status404NotFound, typeof(GroupInfo404Example))]
    [SwaggerResponseExample(Status500InternalServerError, typeof(GroupInfo500Example))]
    [ProducesResponseType(Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(Status403Forbidden)]
    [ProducesResponseType(Status404NotFound)]
    [ProducesResponseType(Status500InternalServerError)]
```

I can get all of them to render except the GroupInfo500Example. The application only returns an HTTP 500 to indicate an internal exception that isn't caught by other exception handlers. It is intended to return a body that contains, among other things, a GUID that can be passed in to our support organization to help them look up the exception in the application logs. I can not get the example to render for any 5xx error. If I change it to another status code, it renders, so it's specifically the 5xx result that doesn't render. I've checked the openapi json produced and it's not produced as part of the generated JSON. Is there a filter in place that keeps 5xx response docs from showing response examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured it out. I was missing part of the 'ProducesResponseType' attribute. It needs to have the return type as well as the HTTP status code. This works:

```
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ADServiceOperationMultipleResult<GroupActionRequestForUsers, UserQuery>), Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ADServiceOperationMultipleResult<GroupActionRequestForUsers, UserQuery>), Status400BadRequest)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ADServiceOperationMultipleResult<GroupActionRequestForUsers, UserQuery>), Status403Forbidden)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ADServiceOperationMultipleResult<GroupActionRequestForUsers, UserQuery>), Status404NotFound)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ADServiceOperationMultipleResult<GroupActionRequestForUsers, UserQuery>), Status422UnprocessableEntity)]
    [ProducesResponseType(typeof(ADServiceOperationMultipleResult<GroupActionRequestForUsers, UserQuery>), Status500InternalServerError)]
```

Oddly enough, some status codes were including the example without it, but now the examples appear consistently as long as I include the method return type in the attribute.